# how to get linkedin connections of a loggedin user in a drupal site

Tags: drupal, linkedin-api

To get the connections of a linkedin user we need to set member permission (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting) . But i did not see any thing about it in http://drupal.org/project/linkedin

Need  help about above mentioned issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires the member permission "r_network" so after adding following patch i got it working for me

linkedin/linkedin.inc

```
if (!isset($_GET['action']) || $_GET['action'] != $_SESSION['random']) {
$_SESSION['random'] = $random;
--$url = $base_url . "/requestToken;
++$url = $base_url . "/requestToken?scope=r_network";
```

Thanks